# AWS Lambda Stops Running Randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Has anyone ever seen a Lambda function stop randomly?

I've got a method that subscribes to an SNS topic that is published to every hour. I recently had 4 messages come through to the subscriber Lambda and 3 of the four worked perfectly.

CloudWatch gives me all of the console logs I have logged, I get responses from all of the APIs the method reaches out to, end with a success message, but the fourth message logs the console log to CloudWatch and then I get the "Request End" log immediately following. None of the following: console.logs, no error from lambda, no insight as to why it would have stopped, no timeout error, it just stopped.

I've never seen this kind of behavior before and have yet to have a Lambda function stop working without logging out the error (everything that runs is written in a try/catch that has reliably logged the errors until now).

Has anyone ever come across this and have any insight as to what it may be?

Comment: Does the Lambda spin up when it gets a notification from SNS or do you have a Lambda function running continuously waiting for input?

Comment: Which language are you using? Functions written in Node are sometimes badly coded for async API calls.

Comment: try increasing the timeout limit of lambda function from 30sec (default) to a higher one.

Comment: try increasing timeout limit and memory if needed it will work for sure.

Comment: I'm also seeing this behaviour.  It essentially hangs until the timeout is reached.  No errors are reported. The Lambda I'm running is using Python3.7.  I've enabled x-ray but not finding anything useful yet.   If I save the Lambda, after enabling x-ray, for example, the Lambda will start working again for a time before failing once more.  Its an intermittent  issue bahh.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour and in my case this happens when there is way too many concurrent executions going on, it just ends abruptly. Please let me know if you happen to know why this is happening and if there are workarounds ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. My lambda is written in Python 3.7 and it is triggered by an SQS queue, it works for a while (up to a few days), and then it starts timing out... No logging - seems like it hangs on startup, at object instantiation. REPORT log, shows that the memory used is well below the limit set. By the look of it - once it times out, it always times out. Did anyone find out how to fix this?

Comment: @Leo Did you fix the issue .i am getting the same issue...Can you help me

Comment: @SEJ for us it was due to the way another project was re-creating a security group when it got deployed. In terraform,  was set up using an inline rule for ingress/egress. It turns out that splitting the rules from the security group definition fixed the issue. I hope it helps!